# fs readFile working in console but not in server Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, console, fs

I want to show the content of my `index.html` file in my webpage

Here is my code in `server.js`

```
  var express = require('express')()
const fs = require('fs');

express.get('/', (request, reponse) => {

    const path = './index.html';

    console.log(path);

    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        fs.readFile('./index.html', "utf8", (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
    else {
        console.log('nope');
    }
```

This code shows my html file content in my console, however it doesn't in my server. The page doesn't stop loading.

EDIT

I wasn't returning my data, I added `reponse.send(data)` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Don't you need to return the content?

Comment: There's no `response.send()` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I added response.send(data) and it works ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just use res.sendFile method to return the html page, you actually don't need to use fs in this scenario.

Example:

```
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
   res.sendFile('home.html');
});
```